# How can I change (remove) a Seahorse password

Tags: seahorse

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and entered a password in SeaHorse. I would like to remove the password of "Default" but I get this error :

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Secret.Error.NoSuchObject: The collection does not exist
```

Is there a fix or a way to bypass modify the password ?

Answer (score 1):

open sea horse:

> Right-click on the "login" keyring
>
> Select "Change password"
>
> Enter your old password

and leave it blank if you want or change it to something else

Comment: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Secret.Error.NoSuchObject: The collection does not exist