# How do I synchronize my keyring password with my account password in Ubuntu Studio 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, password, keyrings

I changed my **account** password (and have autologin engaged, which I believe to be related to my issue), but the **keyring** password remains the same as my former account password.

I thought that maybe I needed to logout and back on to flush queues... but, that did not work.

So, I thought, do a "Microsoft" and reboot... again, this did not work.

My research has uncovered how to synchronize the accounts using KDE (or Gnome) tools. For example in [this article](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/change-login-keyring-password/), I see that older versions of Ubuntu had a "System-Preferences" feature to accomplish this.

How do I change my keyring password, after having changed my account password on Ubuntu Studio 20.04?

Comment: Change your Keyring password: Use your Desktop Search to find the "Passwords and Keys" application (Seahorse). Then follow [How can I change (remove) a Seahorse password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204092/how-can-i-change-remove-a-seahorse-password). Old, but still correct (just tested).

Comment: @user535733, On Ubuntu Studio, typing "passwords" into the desktop search yields no results.

Comment: I now see that the "autologin" does not seem to affect the situation.  I turned it off.  And, upon login, i am prompted for my old (i.e., keyring) password.