# Just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04. Password not working

Tags: upgrade, password

I used the graphical upgrade manager.

Login screen shows my account name, but won't accept the correct password.

I've researched other's solutions, but they all seem to involve bringing up a terminal.  Ctl+alt+t doesnt bring a terminal for me.  Other ctl+function keys don't do anything either.

Keyboard and mouse seem to be working fine.

Is there a default password for a new upgrade?

Thanks,

Ed

Comment: It said "Invalid password" or equivalent.  Using the recovery console, I was able to remove the password from my account, so it is now passwordless. Now, I still get the login screen showing my account name. When I click on it, it now does not offer me a password field, but just disappears briefly, and returns.

Answer (score 0):

"Invalid Password" means you input the wrong password. Your password was not changed by an upgrade.

"Removing" the password is unwise: Accounts without a password cannot be logged into. It simply locks you out of your own account. Better to *change* the password to one you will remember next time.

It is possible to [automatically login without using your password](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html). The account must still have a valid password even though you don't type it at login. You will still need your password to unlock your Keyring and for Admin tasks.

Advice:

1. Use the Recovery Console to set a new password, or restore your old password.
2. If you change your password (no longer the original), remember to also [change the password on your Keyring](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204092/) to match.
3. OPTIONAL: Set up automatic login. If you do so, remember to record your password somewhere so you don't encounter this problem again.

Comment: Same simple password for at least 3 years.  No problem with it until the upgrade.   I've now restored the original password. Symptoms remain--"invalid password".

Comment: Let me add that it actually doesn't say "invalid password" now.  After entering the password, it just goes back to the screen with just my user name.

Comment: Some more detail:  If I enter an intentionally wrong password, I get the "Sorry, that didn't work", but if I enter the correct password, that message does not appear, and it just recycles back to the user name.

Comment: "*Recycles back to the user name*" is vital information. It means you have a *desktop crash*, also known as a *login loop*. When the desktop stack crashes, you get returned to the login page. Search those terms. There are many, many possible causes for a desktop crash, and each has a different solution.

Comment: Well, in the end, I just did a re-install of 20.04.  I lost some things, but at least I'm up and running now.  I'll chalk it up to a failed upgrade. Thanks for the help.